# Converting ETL to XML in powershell using traceprt, issues with dashes and spaces in arguments

Tags: powershell

I am having the hardest time with putting together a wrapper for the tracerpt.exe command in PowerShell. I have tried all my normal tricks for getting spaces in command arguments but, the tracerpt.exe command errors if a wrapper the arguments with quotes. also it seems my dashes are getting stripped out and I don't know why. If anyone knows how I can format the arguments to keep the dashes and the spaces without sending the quotes and really be greatful for the help.

Also, if some one know a better way of converting an ETL to an XML format in PowerShell I'd would be all for a different solution.

```
Function Convert-ETLtoXML
{
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [string]$ETLinputFile

  )
    $space = [char]32
    [string]$confrimOverWrite = '-y'
    [String]$format = "-of" + $space + "XML"
    [string]$outfile = "-o" +$space + "xxyy.xml"
    [string]$command = 'C:\Windows\system32\tracerpt.exe'
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red  "$command $ETLinputFile $confrimOverWrite $format $outfile"

    & $command $ETLinputFile $confrimOverWrite $format $outfile


  }
  Convert-ETLtoXML -ETLinputFile .\DEMO.etl
```

output:

```
C:\Windows\system32\tracerpt.exe .\DEMO.etl -y -of XML -o xxyy.xml
Argument 'of XML' is unknown.
Argument 'o xxyy.xml' is unknown.
```

Error:
The parameter is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work for me:

```
Function Convert-ETLtoXML
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$ETLinputFile
    )
    $Command = {C:\Windows\system32\tracerpt.exe $ETLinputFile -y -of XML -o xxyy.xml}

    Write-Host -Object $Command.ToString() -ForegroundColor Red 

    $Command.Invoke()
}
Convert-ETLtoXML -ETLinputFile .\DEMO.etl
```

Comment: thank you so much, I just learned a new way of invoking a command.