# ETL file parsing using powershell script

Tags: parsing, etl, powershell-2.0, windows-scripting, get-winevent

#Defining the etl file
$etlFile = 'test.etl'

#Retrieving the content
$log = Get-WinEvent -Path $etlFile –Oldest

Is there any other way of parsing .etl file to read etw events?

Comment: Why not use get-winevent?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in command for reading an etl file with PowerShell but calling *tracerpt.exe* in *windows\system32* for converting the etl file into xml (the file is always called **dumpfile.xml**) seems to be a simple solution:

```
tracerpt.exe .\WindowsUpdate.20220813.100210.641.1.etl -lr
([Xml](Get-Content .\dumpfile.xml)).Events
([Xml](Get-Content .\dumpfile.xml)).Events.Event
([Xml](Get-Content .\dumpfile.xml)).Events.Event.EventData
([Xml](Get-Content .\dumpfile.xml)).Events.Event.EventData.Data
etc.
```

See also [Converting ETL to XML in powershell using traceprt, issues with dashes and spaces in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100986/converting-etl-to-xml-in-powershell-using-traceprt-issues-with-dashes-and-space)